# Imageview frame.origin.x frame.origin.y always return 0,0

Tags: ios, imageview

I have an imageview predefined on the screen, I want to draw something on top of it, not exactly on it, but next to it, however, when I query `[imageview frame.origin.x]` and `[imageview frame.origin.y]` I always get `0, 0`, which is the top left corner of the screen, not the imageview. How do I get the x, y coordinates of the predefined imageview ?

This is my code for querying the image:

```
 -(void) drawMyImage:(UIImage *)image nextTo:(UIImageView *)imageView{
    CGRect frame = [imageView frame];
    int startX = frame.origin.x+10;
    int startY = frame.origin.y;
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX,startY,frame.size.width,frame.size.height)];
    myImageView .image = image;
    [myImageView setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

And my image is always drawn in the top left corner of the screen. How can I fix this?

Comment: make sure imageView instance is not nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was
i was defining everything in viewDidLoad, when i should have done it in viewDidAppear, when IB objects have frames

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use float value rather that using int.

Comment: that does not help, is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `[myImageView setNeedsDisplay];` to `[imageView addSubView:myImageView];`

Comment: i dont want my image to be a subview of imageview i want it to be a subview of the self.view object, but i want it displayed next to the imageview i passed as the parameter, and since the origin always returns 0,0 , my image always adds at the top left corner of the screen